# Cant join 2 strings in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Hey am trying to make a javafx program that join two strings but i am getting error when trying to join them with join command. My javafx code is

```
String name = "John";
String lastname= "doe";
   String fullname = name.join(lastname);
```

I don't know this is correct or it's my foolishness to use this as i am beginner to javafx. I hope you can resolve my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: String doesn't have a join method. use a StringBuffer or simple concatenation instead

Comment: `.join()` method is used in threading . i dont find them in string concatenation

Comment: Can you please tell me how to correct it? . I don't know how to join two strings

Comment: name + lastname
this is very basic String handling, learn the basics before trying to go to JafaFX

Comment: I know i don't know basics but i am trying to learn that and according to me i can learn it by making practical programs. I am a 13 year teen only.I have learned many programming languages like php like this only

Answer (score 4):

```
String name = "John";
String lastname= "doe";
String fullname = String.join(" ", name, lastname);
```

As in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-):

```
public static String join(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence... elements)
```

But you could simply use concatenation:

```
String fullname = name + " " + lastname;
```